Video loaded from URL not working in html page
I am on OSX 14.6, and would like to embed this video, stored here in webm format  and here in mp4 format, into this webpage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<center>

<video width="640" height="480" controls autoplay muted playsinline loop>
    <!-- read locally -->
    <!-- <source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
    <!-- read from url as mp4 -->
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rgxwvsl9wz9i0qn52kdmg/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!-- read from url as webm -->
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kv0sc5r5ljnyf4v7szl7a/animation.webm" type="video/webm">    
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>

</center>

</body>
</html>

When I load the webpage on Chrome (version 128.0.6613.138) or Safari 17.6, the video is not played, see screenshot. On the other hand, if I read the .mp4 file locally from my hard drive as in the line
<source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">

the video is played properly. And yes, I tried this solution and it does not work.
Why ?
Thank you

It could be because the dropbox URL requires log in credentials

If the link has /scl/fi/ then it also needs to have an rlkey included in the link. See DropBox documentation for more details.

Side note, the <center> doesn't exist anymore. Use CSS

This works locally because your machine has privileges to access the protected video file hosted by Dropbox.  The comment from JamesS is accurate; the video is not available publicly and requires a Dropbox account with access to the file.
Check your console in the browser and you'll see the error for the failed request to load the video.

The video needs to be located where the web server can access it.  The easy thing to do is upload it with your website and place it in a folder, such as "/assets".  Edit your page to request the file in it's new location: src="assets/animation.mp4".  If you are having trouble sorting out the relative path to the assets folder, this might help:   https://www.jquery-az.com/html-img-src-image-source-attribute-with-path-possibilities-5-examples/
